# C Socket, server and client. connect error: "No route to Host"

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I've written the client code and the server, however, there is a problem with connect: "No route to host".  It is strange because clients and servers operate in a different network.  Also, if I ping [my ip] tells me timeout, if I telnet [my ip] tells me error.  Can you advise me how to solve this problem? I opened port 2222 from the router but it still does not seem to work.
Sorry for my English

**Client code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define ADDRESS "[IP]"  
#define PORT 2222 

int main()
{
    int sockid;
    struct sockaddr_in c_address;
    printf("[CLIENT] Eseguito.\n");

    c_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    c_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDRESS);
    c_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int sock_conn;
    sock_conn = connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr *)&c_address, sizeof(c_address));
    if(sock_conn == -1)
    {
        perror("Connect client");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        char text[128];
        printf("[CLIENT] Scrivi qualcosa: ");
        fgets(text, 128, stdin);
        write(sockid, text, 128);
        read(sockid, text, 128);
        printf("[CLIENT] Testo ricevuto: %s.\n", text);
    }
}
```

**Server code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 2222 

void toggleCharacter(char *str);

int main()
{
    int sockid;
    struct sockaddr_in s_address;
    printf("[SERVER] Eseguito.\n");

    s_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    s_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr *)&s_address, sizeof(s_address)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Bind server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(listen(sockid, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror("Listen server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int connection_socket;
    connection_socket = accept(sockid, NULL, 0);
    if(connection_socket == -1)
    {
        perror("Accept server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char text[128];
    while(1)
    {
        read(connection_socket, text, 128);
        printf("[SERVER] Messaggio ricevuto: %s.\n", text);
        printf("[SERVER] Scrivi qualcosa: ");
        fgets(text, 128, stdin);
        write(connection_socket, text, 128);
    }
    close(connection_socket);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text directly in your question instead of providing links to code.

Comment: If ping and telnet aren't able to reach the server's IP-address, your code won't either, no matter how you tweaked it. Have a look what *IP-routing* is and how it is configured on the platforms involved.

Comment: Do you have any advice for me on what to edit? :/ Thanks for your answers

Comment: you should configure your AP to redirect request for the port 2222  to your computer's ip address, and the client should connect with the AP ip not the computer ip.